# Frameworks vs models

Tags: deep-learning, machine-learning-model, dataframe

My second question ([Models vs algorithms](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/123985/models-vs-algorithms)) is what is the difference between models and frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at definitions first. According to Wikipedia:

*In computer programming, a **software framework** is an abstraction in which software, providing generic functionality, can be selectively changed by additional user-written code, thus providing application-specific software*

*A **mathematical model** is an abstract description of a concrete system using mathematical concepts and language*

The first remark might be that both **framework** and **model** are multipronged and ambiguous terms. I had to narrow them down to **software framework** and **mathematical model** based on the context to attempt to answer your question.

Based on these definitions you might note that both these terms describe abstractions that can be used within some broader system. However, *as I understand*, a model is a description of something, when a framework doesn't have to. I perceive a framework to often be a bag of tools or a set of functionalities when a model attempts to utilise a relationship between some concepts. For instance, TensorFlow is a framework, but a neural network might be a model.

Comment: So lets say sklearn is framework , regression  is model and the regression procedure inside the model is algorithm. ..

Comment: And can we say os(operating system) also kind of framework